# Use UNNEST inside JOOQ's select

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I have the SQL like:

```sql
select *
from some_table
where (select array(select unnest(first_array_field) except select unnest(second_array_field))) @> '{some_value}';
```

This is my try to write the `where` condition for that query in a JOOQ way:

```java
  private Condition selectAwayValue(
      List<Long> list) {

    var allSelect = dslContext
        .select(TABLE.ARRAY_1)
        .from(DSL.unnest(TABLE.ARRAY_1));

    var homeSelect = dslContext
        .select(TABLE.ARRAY_2)
        .from(DSL.unnest(TABLE.ARRAY_2));

    var awaySelect = allSelect.except(homeSelect);

    var awayArray = dslContext.select(DSL.array(awaySelect));

    return awayArray.asField().contains(awayCompetitorIdsList);
  }
```

I'm facing 2 problems here:

1. I got the different SQL than I expected (see above)
2. Also got the exception like `Cannot convert from 5 (class java.lang.Long) to class [Ljava.lang.Long;`

I understand what's the exceptions says to me, but don't understand why :)

What's would be the best way to write my SQL in a jooq syntax?

I'm using the latest stable jooq version, the latest stable Postgres version

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Alternative solution

If you think of your problem this way:

```sql
select *
from some_table
where first_array_field @> '{some_value}'
and not second_array_field @> '{some_value}';
```

Then, the problem is a lot simpler to express in jOOQ as well

```java
ctx.selectFrom(SOME_TABLE)
   .where(SOME_TABLE.FIRST_ARRAY_FIELD.contains(new Long[] { someValue }))
   .andNot(SOME_TABLE.SECOND_ARRAY_FIELD.contains(new Long[] { someValue }))
   .fetch();
```

#### Why your solution didn't work

Of course, you could pull this off using your own approach. Regarding the problems you've observed:

> I got the different SQL than I expected (see above)

That syntax where you put `UNNEST()` in `SELECT` is not supported by jOOQ. It is quite the weird syntax in PostgreSQL as well, and doesn't do what you might think it does in many ways. Have you tried putting two instances of `UNNEST()` in `SELECT`? The second one won't form a cartesian product like the first one. Rows from it will be matched with the first one's rows by ordinality.

However, using `UNNEST` in `FROM` is correct and also more intuitive in native PostgreSQL, even if it's a bit longer. And it's supported by jOOQ.

> Also got the exception like Cannot convert from 5 (class java.lang.Long) to class [Ljava.lang.Long;

This is because you seem to be calling [`Field.contains()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html#contains(T)) with a scalar argument, instead of an array. See the example from the Javadoc, or my example above:

```
 // Use this expression
 val(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 }).contains(new Integer[] { 1, 2 })

 // ... to render this SQL
 ARRAY[1, 2, 3] @> ARRAY[1, 2]
```

But again, I think my alternative approach is much simpler.